# Proving that every boolean function can be represented as a propositional logic formula.

Tags: logic

I'm currently struggling a bit on this question. I tried induction on the number of parameters.

Induction.

Start $n=0$:

Let $f$ be a boolean function with $0$ parameters.

2 Cases: $f()=0$ or $f()=1$

For case 1 we have a formula like $a \land \lnot a$

Case 2 formula $a \lor \lnot a$

Now the induction step is where i am struggling:

$f(x_1,x_2,...x_n,x_{n+1})=1$ or

$f(x_1,x_2,...x_n,x_{n+1})=0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the [conjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form), or the [disjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) no induction needed, really. Both obey your requirements, I think.

But if you want induction, try: given $f: \{0,1\}^{n+1} \to \{0,1\}$ define the "sections" $g_0: \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}$ by $g_0(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = f(x_1,\ldots,x_n, 0)$ and $g_1$ similarly with $x_{n+1} = 1$.

By induction represent $g_0(x_1,\ldots, x_n) = \phi_0(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ using some formula with $\land, \lor$ and $\lnot$ in the terms $x_i$. Ditto with $g_1$ and some $\phi_1$. Then $$f(x_1, \ldots,x_n, x_{n+1}) = (\phi_0(x_0,\ldots,x_n) \land \lnot x_{n+1}) \lor (\phi_1(x_0,\ldots,x_n) \land x_{n+1})$$

which is also of the required form.

Comment: Well, if one happens to want a _formal_ proof, I don't think we can get around using induction _somewhere_. But it can probably he hidden away with some appropriate handwaving in an ordinary prose argument.

Comment: @HenningMakholm one way is to use one conjunction for every preimage of $1$. I don't see any induction there ,you can just define it from the truth table.

Comment: yes i know dnf works, but i wanted to use induction. Thanks

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: I think (again, to be completely formal) that one needs induction to prove an arbitrary element of the domain has a conjunction corresponding to it.

Comment: Why can i define $g_0$ as equal to a function  $f$ who has one parameter more ?

Comment: @asddf $g_0$ has $n$ parameters and we use $f$ with the last variable fixed to $0$ to define its value.

Comment: ok i got it, thanks